Excel VBA Paste Issue
Below is my sub routine.  The line below is where the code stops every single time with 1004 error message.  When I hit "Debug" the sheet seems to populate with the copied data and I can continue on with the code without any issues until it comes back to the line again and the same error presents itself.  It is like the copy of the values isn't finished.
'Sets the active workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        
    'Finds the last populated row in the of the unique consultants in PDF Data spreadsheet
    LastRow = wb.Sheets("Queries").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    
    x = 7
    
    Do Until x > LastRow
        wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Range("A3").Value = wb.Sheets("Queries").Range("G" & x).Value
        
        If wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Range("A3").Value <> "" Then
            If wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Range("A3").Value <> "0" Then
                wb.Sheets("PDF Data").Activate
                ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PDF_tbl").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Range("A3").Value
                
                PDFDataLastRow = wb.Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
                
                wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Range("A6:N6").Clear
                wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Range("A7:N9999").Delete
                wb.Sheets("PDF Data").Range("PDF_tbl[[#All],[Customer ID]:[Total AR]]").Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Range("A5")
                'wb.Sheets("PDF Data").Range("C5:P9999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                'wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                
                'Adds subtotals
                **wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Range("A1").Select**
                PDFLayoutLastRow = wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Range("A5:N" & PDFLayoutLastRow).Select
                Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=2, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), Replace:=True, Pagebreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
                
                wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Activate
                ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="Z:\BenF\Aging\PDF\" & Replace(Replace(wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Range("A3").Value, ",", ""), ".", "") & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".pdf"
                
                Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Add
                wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Copy Before:=wbCopy.Sheets(1)
                wbCopy.SaveAs "Z:\BenF\Aging\Excel\" & Replace(Replace(wb.Sheets("PDF Layout").Range("A3").Value, ",", ""), ".", "") & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
                wbCopy.Close
            End If
        End If
            
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Excel and PDF files have been created.", vbOKOnly

Expectation is that the bolded line will work.  I tried placing other lines there that interact with the same worksheet and it still errors out.  It is almost as if the paste isn't finished.

You can't Select a range on that sheet unless you activate the sheet first, but avoid using Select.

Activate worked. that was nice easy solution since I couldn't see what the problem was after starting at it forever.  Thank you.

Please consider rewriting your code to avoid using Select. The "nice easy solution" is the wrong one.
